# MS Teams - Open document in Ready only mode

Tags: office365, ms-office, microsoft-teams

I'm working on a case where client requested the following requirement, whenever a user opens any document then by default it should open in Read only mode.

Word document is opening in Read only mode by default, but when i'm opening excel file its opening in Editing mode (attached below). So is there any way we can set any document mode to read only in MS Teams by default.
[image]

Comment: Are you still facing issue?

Answer (score -1):

You can Enable Read only property when you upload the file to teams. Before sharing the file you can set file to read only. Could you please check the below screen shot?
[image]
You can disable the Allow editing property as shown in the image before uploading.
[image]